# Settings -> About phone -> Battery use bug?

Tags: battery, battery-life, samsung-galaxy-s-plus

When I open the "Battery use" screen it says that the phone is on battery for 14663d 4h 34m 53s, which is clearly wrong. The graph shows a linearly descending line. What is the problem? Why does the phone display these values? As far as I can tell the feature has been working correctly so far.

I have tried restarting the phone (I've removed the battery for a short time too). The phone is a Samsung Galaxy S Plus with firmware version 2.3.5.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried plugging it in, letting it charge a bit, then unplugging it? That ought to reset the battery statistics.

Comment: Yes, I've tried but didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should attempt to re-calibrate your battery.

Google Android battery calibration and have read. There are a number of sites that describe the process and even some apps that claim to do it (I haven't tried any, so I can't vouch for them).

Answer (score 0):

If you are rooted you can use [Battery Caliberation](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nema.batterycalibration&hl=en) App  to recaliberate your battery.
It will reset your battery status.